# How to pass an argument to boost::thread?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

```
thread_ = boost::thread( boost::function< void (void)>( boost::bind( &clientTCP::run , this ) ) );
```

is it possible that run has an argument like this :

```
void clientTCP::run(boost:function<void(std::string)> func);
```

and if yes how my boost::thread call should be written

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The following code `boost::bind( &clientTCP::run , this )` defines a function callback. It calls the function `run` on the current instance (`this`). With boost::bind you can do the following:

```
// Pass pMyParameter through to the run() function
boost::bind(&clientTCP::run, this, pMyParameter)
```

See the documentation and example here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html

> If you wish to construct an instance
>   of boost::thread with a function or
>   callable object that requires
>   arguments to be supplied, this can be
>   done by passing additional arguments
>   to the boost::thread constructor:

```
void find_the_question(int the_answer);

boost::thread deep_thought_2(find_the_question,42);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 9):

I just wanted to note, for future work, that Boost by default passes the arguments by value. So if you want to pass a reference you have the `boost::ref()` and `boost::cref()` methods, the latter for constant references.

I think you can still use the `&` operator for referencing, but I'm not sure, I have always used `boost::ref`.

Answer (score 9):

```
thread_ = boost::thread( boost::function< void (void)>( boost::bind( &clientTCP::run , this ) ) );
```

The `bind` **and** the `function` are unnecessary, and make the code slower and use more memory. Just do:

```
thread_ = boost::thread( &clientTCP::run , this );
```

To add an argument just add an argument:

```
thread_ = boost::thread( &clientTCP::run , this, f );
```