# passing an argument to a boost::thread constructer

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a function that takes a PCL point cloud as an argument.

```
void PointCloudOdometry::addKeyFrame(PointCloud::Ptr map_base)
{

...
```

I am trying to start a boost::thread that runs this function.

`PointCloud::Ptr msg_base(new PointCloud);`

`boost::thread workerThread(&addKeyFrame, msg_base);`

According to this:

[How to pass an argument to boost::thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730747/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-boostthread)

this should work. But I am getting:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2276   '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression
```

What am i missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `addKeyFrame` a class member function?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Both `addkeyframe` and the function containing the thread constructor are in the same class /namespace.

Comment: As in the duplicate: ` workerThread = new boost::thread(&PointCloudOdometry::addKeyFrame, this, msg_base);` works here. Thank you